# Transfer of stocks and shares ISA as a Non-UK resident

Tags: united-kingdom, isa

I am a UK/German citizen currently living in Germany.  When I left the UK for Germany I kept my stocks and shares ISA in case I should ever return to the UK.  Whilst I know that I cannot add funds to the ISA and that I have to pay tax on divis and gains in Germany, I wish to transfer the ISA to a different provider as I am dissatisfied with the current one.  Does anyone know if such a transfer is actually  forbidden by HMRC?

ECG